# How to set high resolution on external monitor?

Tags: screen-resolution, external-display

I have Samsung Galaxy S3. I connect my phone to 29 inch monitor using HML + HDMI wires. Also I connect it to Apple bluetooth keyboard and magic mouse. I get a very nice experience of Desktop. However S3 has maximum resolution of 1280x720 which does not give a nice look on big monitors.

I have following questions:

- Can I extend my monitor screen from mobile screen so I can drag and drop apps from one to another?
- Can I change resolution of apps running on my monitor to higher than 1280x720.

Thanks

Note: External monitor does not have touch functionality.

Comment: I doubt that the graphics chip in the S3 is able to produce higher resolutions.

Comment: And what about using Miracast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a different external display was one of the new features with [Jelly Bean 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html)  You will need a siutable update for your S3 to stand a chance.  What level of support you will get then is still in doubt depending upon the real hardware capabilities and what support Samsung put in.

Comment: Great. I have seen 4.2 documentation. When I had asked this question, 4.2 was not released yet. Do you have real life experience on this feature?

Comment: No real life experiance sorry.